# Programmatically create new columns using column names in a vector with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If we have the following data.table:

```
x <- data.table(`2021` = rep(10, 3), `2022` = rep(5, 3))
```

we can create a new column like this:

```
x[, d := `2022` / `2021` -1]
```

Now I want to save 2022 and 2021 in a vector like this:

```
years <- c("2021", "2022")
x[, d := years[2] / years[1] -1]
```

but of course, this doesn't work. I tried to use `eval` and `as.name` but it doesn't work in that specific case.  How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get` when you want to tell the data.table that you are referring to something inside its environment (the dt itself) or higher (see ?get)

```
x[, d := get(years[2])  / get(years[1]) -1]
```

Comment: Since I am not using the last data.table version as @Uwe suggest, I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

With [*development* version 1.14.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has gained the new `env` argument (see the new vignette *programming on data.table*). So, the recommended way is

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.3 used here
years <- c("2021", "2022")
x[, d := yr2 / yr1 - 1, env = list(yr1 = years[1], yr2 = years[2])][]
```

or

```
x[, d := yrs[[2]] / yrs[[1]] - 1, env = list(yrs = as.list(years))][]
```

Both return

> ```
>    2021 2022    d
> 1:   10    5 -0.5
> 2:   10    5 -0.5
> 3:   10    5 -0.5
> ```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `.SD` to subset

```
x[, d := .SD[[years[2]]]/.SD[[years[1]]] - 1]
```